# Shiny on Ubuntu machine

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

```
[2019-01-03T18:20:08.983] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.9.923 (Node.js v8.11.3)
[2019-01-03T18:20:08.986] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2019-01-03T18:20:09.047] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2019-01-03T18:20:09.055] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
[2019-01-03T18:20:09.060] [ERROR] shiny-server - HTTP server error (http://[::]:3838): listen EAFNOSUPPORT :::3838
[2019-01-03T18:20:09.060] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

This is the shiny server status:

```
shiny-server stop/waiting
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?, also have a look at this https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/153

Comment: using Ubuntu 14.04 version. 
I tried the steps given in the link you have mentioned but it did not work